# reactive form with dynamic inputs

Tags: angular, angular2-forms

What is the best way to use FormBuilder if I have a dynamic form 
meaning that I can to add one or many phone number for the user, one or many contact mail.

Comment: use `FormArray` to group FormGroup which can handle dynamic form

Answer (score 0):

FormGroup is for defined fields and FormArray is for dynamic fields. Here you can find examples for both: [Angular Reactive Forms](http://www.concretepage.com/angular-2/angular-2-formgroup-example)